# ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword: update using with

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword error when using "update" with "with".

This is giving the error.

```
with wr_double as
(select...)

update work_request r 
set r.name = r.name || '_old'
where exists 
(select 1 from wr_double wd
where wd.name = r.name and wd.wr_id = r.id)
```

But this works fine

```
with wr_double as
(select...)

select * from work_request r 
where exists 
(select 1 from wr_double wd
where wd.name = r.name and wd.wr_id = r.id)
```

Also, if I place my sub-query from the with in the body of the update it works fine.

```
update work_request r 
set r.name = r.name || '_old'
where exists 
(select 1 from 
(select 
wr.name, 
wr.id as wr_id, 
dup_wr.count,
d.id as d_id, 
d.create_date
from 
(select...) wd
where wd.name = r.name and wd.wr_id = r.id)
```

Can I not use "with" in this way with an "update"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to write below way because CTE is part of the SELECT not the UPDATE

```
update work_request 
set name = name || '_old'

   where exists (
      with wr_double as
         (select...)
      select 1 from wr_double wd  wd.name = work_request.name and wd.wr_id = work_request.id
     );
```

Comment: @Hopper - that documentation says that what fallingdog was doing is allowed; but that's because it's MySQL documentation, not Oracle RDBMS. In Oracle a CTE is only allowed [as part of a select](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2077142) (including, as here, in a subquery).

Comment: @Zaynul - that did it! Thanks!